# Set username as default value in Access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access table with a column `username`. I have multiple users that will use the database at different times and they will add rows to the table. But everytime a user add a new row, his/her username must appear in the username column of the table, without them having to type it in by themselves. I tried putting in `UCase(Environ("USERNAME"))` as the default value, but Environ is an unknown function. I use  this `UCase(Environ("USERNAME"))` in VBA to get the user name when i export tables.

Is there any way i can set the deafult value of a column to a user's username?

Comment: How are the users adding records to the table? If your answer is directly, then there is your problem ! If they are using Forms, then you could make use of the Form's button events.

Comment: They will add it like they would with a normal table, but the table will be viewed within a form (a form within a form). But thanks for the tip. I will look into button events and i also don't mind using VBA to do it if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Create a **public function** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32565953/3820271):

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String
    ' GetUserName = Environ("USERNAME")
    ' Environ("USERNAME") is easily spoofed, see comment by HansUp
    GetUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
End Function
```

and use `=GetUserName()` as default value for the control.