# How to use system username directly in MS Access query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to know if there is a way to get system username and use it directly in an MS Access query. I have made a parameter work within a query from a combo box on a form and I have also acquired system name in Access VBA using ENVIRON ("USERNAME").

Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a VBA function that returns the username, and then use the function in the query.

```vb
Public Function GetUserName() As String
    ' GetUserName = Environ("USERNAME")
    ' Better method, see comment by HansUp
    GetUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
End Function
```

and

```sql
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE myUserName = GetUserName();
```

Comment: `Environ("USERNAME")` can be spoofed easily.  A more secure alternative is `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`

Comment: Thank you Andre451 and HansUp. This answers my question perfectly. I was not aware of Environ beinf spoofed easily. will replace it with CreateObject in my code.

Answer (score 1):

My solution kept all the work in VB.
I used a variable for the windows login username and then created a SQL string with that variable inserted.  Lastly, I updated the query behind the form to use this new SQL string.

The `CHR(34)` puts quotes around the name as it is now a string inside the SQLSTR and needs to be within a set of quotes.

If you have a complex SQL statement, write it in the QBE using a string for the name and all the other variables, then switch to the SQL view and replace it using a VBA variable as shown below.

```
MyName = Environ("username")

sqlstr = "SELECT * From Projects WHERE ( ((Projects.LeadEngineer)=" & Chr(34) & MyName & Chr(34) & " AND ActiveYN = True ));"

Forms![Main Form].RecordSource = sqlstr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SYSTEM_USER if the query is being executed in a SQL Server, that will retrieve the user name connected to the database (for that, make sure you are not using fixed user name in your connection string)

Answer (score -1):

Yes - you can use the 'CurrentUser' function in your query. Here I've included it as a field and criteria.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, [CurrentUser] AS UserName FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = [CurrentUser];
```

Comment: `CurrentUser` is the Access username, though (typically "admin" if not specified in the Access command line), not the system (Windows) username.

Comment: Yes you're right - I thought he was after the current user.

Comment: Hi Tuppeny, yes i was getting Admin when I executed that query. My aim was to get the name of the user who was logged on.