# How to get windows username in MS Access VBA on Windows Server 2008

Tags: ms-access, vba, windows-server-2008

I am using this code in my MS Access VBA:
[How to get logged-in user's name in Access vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677112/how-to-get-logged-in-users-name-in-access-vba)

It works perfectly fine.
However, our foreign employees need to use the software on a server, and it is unable to retrieve the username.
We are signed in as usual.
The server version is Windows Server 2008 SP2.

Any suggestions?

Best regards, Emil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know **which** method you are using (there are several answers), but this one suggested by HansUp is easy and hopefully works on the Server too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32565953/3820271

```vb
Public Function GetUserName() As String
    ' GetUserName = Environ("USERNAME")
    ' Better method, see comment by HansUp
    GetUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
End Function
```